# Drawing a rectangle

Tags: diagrams

What is the easiest way to draw a rectangle on latex? I just need a simple rectangle for my students to enter the final answer of a question and I am hoping I don't have to learn anything fancy like Tikz.

Comment: Try using something like `\fbox{\phantom{This is how big an answer would be.}}` http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Boxes#framebox

Comment: Or use `\fbox{\strut\rule{10cm}{0pt}}`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could just do something simple like this

```
\documentclass{article}
\newcommand\answerbox{%%
    \fbox{\rule{1in}{0pt}\rule[-0.5ex]{0pt}{4ex}}}
\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{document}

Put you answer here: \answerbox

\end{document}
```

which requires no use of `TikZ`.

[image]

A bit of an explanation.

The syntax for `\rule` is as follows:

```
\rule[<lift>]{<width>}{<height>}
```

I use two separate `\rule` commands because if I wrote something like

```
\rule{1in}{4ex}
```

I just get a solid black box defeating the purpose.

By using a negative value for `<lift>` I can drop the bottom of the box below the baseline.

`\fbox` then adds more space.  These values are controlled with the following lengths

```
\fboxrule
\fboxsep
```

Generally, `\fboxrule` is `0.4pt` and `\fboxsep` is `3pt`, but you can adjust those values as desired.

Comment: It would be helpful if this answer explained what the adjustable parameters were. I think the 1in is the width and 4ex is the height. Is the -0.5ex how much to sink it below the baseline?

Comment: @BenCrowell Updated with requested information.

Answer (score 9):

Nothing fancy with `tikz`. It is *easy* (this answer is for just showing it).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
  Your answer: \tikz[baseline=0.6ex]\draw (0,0) rectangle (10cm,3ex);

  Your answer: \tikz[baseline=-4pt]\node[draw,minimum width=10cm,minimum height=3ex] {};
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I don't know why but when I type your code on my document, I get crazy slanted lines instead of a rectangle... (I hate tikz... :P)

Answer (score 7):

Actually, if all you want is a box for an answer, I'd say tikz might actually be the most readable (syntactically, at least) way to do this.

**A box as wide as the text, 1in tall, is just:**

`\tikz \draw (0,0) rectangle (\linewidth, 1in);`

> [image]

The point (0,0) just references the current position in the text, then `\linewidth` gives it the right width (which will adjust if you change your margins, and then just set the height, `1in` is just arbitrary.

Make sure to use `\noindent` before beginning the picture, as it *will* try to indent the drawing and that'll cause weird alignment issues.

Here's a simple MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
    % question here
    \lipsum[1]
    \noindent\\
    \tikz \draw (0,0) rectangle (\linewidth, 1in);
\end{document}
```

You could also use standard `\begin{tikzpicture}` `\end{tikzpicture}` brackets like with any other environment, but I used `\tikz` instead because this drawing is only one line long. The draw command is one line long either way.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
    \lipsum[1]
    \noindent\\
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \draw (0,0) rectangle (\linewidth, 1in);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

---

---

I know you asked for something other than `tikz`, but I felt the same way as you until I finally took the plunge recently. The water's warm, I think you'll like it too.

The biggest advantage to using `tikz` is being able to make a fancier answer box easily, for example, the line:

`\tikz \draw[fill=green!5] (0,0) rectangle (\linewidth, -1in) node[pos=.1]{Answer Here:};`

Gives you a 5% green fill and a label:

> [image]

The draw option `[fill=green!5]` fills the path with 5% green, and `node[pos=.1]{Answer Here:}` makes a node (`tikz`'s awesome placement tool) 10% of the way into the box (it measures diagonally, `pos=1` would set the text at the bottom right corner).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
    \lipsum[1]
    \noindent\\
    \tikz \draw[fill=green!5] (0,0) rectangle (\linewidth, -1in) node[pos=.1]{Answer Here:};
\end{document}
```

---

## Good luck!

Answer (score 4):

This command draws a box filling the `linewidth` (you could adjust that, of course), and allowing you to specify how tall the box is.

It creates a box of specified height using `\raisebox` and then draws lines around it and specifies the width using `\framebox`.

It uses an optional argument, so `\answerbox` defaults to a height of `3\baselineskip`, but you can change it with `\answerbox[0.5\textwidth]` or any other length.

```
\documentclass{article}
\newcommand{\answerbox}[1][3\baselineskip]{%
    \noindent\framebox[\linewidth]{%
        \raisebox{0pt}[0pt][#1]{}%
    }\par\medskip%
}
\begin{document}
Write your answer here:

\answerbox

Write another answer here:

\answerbox[5\baselineskip]

\end{document}
```

[image]